# NSDictionary data not persist

Tags: iphone

I have a NSDictionary object containing array of objects for particular keys, problem is that I call a function in a class which populate this dictionary and return, when I access object for key it returns me an array containing same number of objects as I inserted but when I try to access the individual objects in this array I got an obj_msgsend error,
I would be really thankful if someone can help me out.

Comment: Can you post some of your code?

Comment: it sounds like you're releasing your objects when you shouldn't be.

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like you may have a class in your NSDictionary that does not implement the NSCoding protocol.